# hiccup form-helper with compojure

Tags: clojure, compojure, hiccup

Exception: Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not locate hiccup/form_helpers__init.class or hiccup/form_helpers.clj on classpath:

I'm trying to get a toy compojure app up and running. The original app was from CloudBees and their ClickStart app for Clojure/Compojure. I'm trying to add a simple form (that won't persist anything yet) using hiccup form_helpers but I'm getting a ClassNotFound exception. Here's what I've done:

project.clj:

```
(defproject mywebapp "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
:description "FIXME: write description"
:url "http://example.com/FIXME"
:dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.4.0"]
             [compojure "1.1.1"]
             [hiccup "1.0.1"]]
:plugins [[lein-ring "0.7.3"]]
:ring {:handler mywebapp.routes/app}
:profiles
{:dev {:dependencies [[ring-mock "0.1.3"]]}})
```

views.clj:

```
(ns mywebapp.views
(:use [hiccup core page]
    [hiccup form-helpers :only [form-to label text-area submit-button]]))
...
(defn shout-form []
[:div {:id "shout-form" }
 (form-to [:post "/form"]
        (label "shout" "What do you want to SHOUT?")
        [:br]
        (text-area "shout")
        [:br]
        (submit-button "SHOUT!"))])
...
```

Answer (score 3):

Ah, looks like I just had an old example of forms in hiccup. form_helpers was from a previous version.

if I change my views.clj file  from this:

```
(:use [hiccup form-helpers])
```

to look like this:

```
(:use [hiccup form])
```

(and presumably this would work though i haven't tested it):

```
(:use [hiccup form :only [form-to label text-area submit-button]])
```

I don't get the error anymore.

To clarify: the package used to be called "form_helpers" and is now simply called "form".

Comment: I don't get why the change fixes the issue? Could you elaborate?

Comment: see my edit - sorry i was unclear. (didn't think anyone noticed my question/answer)

Comment: That's much better now. Thanks a lot! Could you please also add the exception to the question so it has all the information? That would make the question and the answer complete.

Comment: i don't have the exact exception anymore. It was just a ClassNotFound exception - kind of like when your code expects a dependency to be in your classpath but doesn't find it.

Comment: I understand. With the exception's stack trace the question and the answer would be more complete and perhaps Google searches would lead more often.

Comment: added the exception, fyi Jacek